# How to check if a specific pixel is transparent

Tags: uwp, transparency, bitmapimage

How do I check if the pixel at a specific point on a `BitmapImage` is transparent?

This is easy if using a `WriteableBitmapEx` or if using some WPF stuff, but it's not super clear in UWP.

The first step would be getting the information for each pixel, then checking a specific pixel (or iterating through them if needed). Then you'd check the alpha value. How would you go about actually doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
public static async Task<bool> IsPixelTransparent(Point hitPosition, BitmapImage sourceImage)
{
        IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(sourceImage.UriSource).OpenReadAsync();
        randomStream.Seek(0);

        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomStream);
        PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        byte[] Pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

        int rowWidth = (int)decoder.PixelWidth * 4;
        int rowOffset = hitPosition.Y * rowWidth;
        int colOffset = hitPosition.X * 4;
        int totalOffset = rowOffset + colOffset;

        byte alpha = Pixels[totalOffset + 3];

        return alpha == 0;
}
```

It could probably use some optimisations, but after a few tests it seems to work.